# Invention of the SI unit of plane angle:Radian

Tags: discoveries

As I was reading on the topic plane angle then I came across a term radian.Hence I want to know how radians were discovered as well ?

Comment: Regarding the measure itself, [Roger Cotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Cotes) is credited with first using it in its current sense (1714) although other measures of angle by arc length were used previously.  Regarding the name "radian", [Jeff Miller's site](http://jeff560.tripod.com/r.html) states that it was Lord Kelvin's brother, James Thomson, and James Muir who first introduced the term which is a shortened form of *radial angle* in the late 19th century.

Comment: It's not really a discovery.... other than that  $circumference = 2*\pi*radius$